# How can I check how many values are inside a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sum 6 values with a button entered into a single field.

For that I would need to know how to check how many values are inside a variable so I can make an if to disable the button once it reaches 6 entries and sum those values so they can be shown in a paragraph.

I'm using JQuery

Comment: Make another variable that will serve as a counter!

Comment: How your actual code looks like ? you can just count the number of clicks and do `++` each time you click

Comment: What is the structure of the field, do you have a separator, could you please provide an example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/92wew4b5/

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```js
let pressCounter = 0,
total = 0,
inputVal = 0;
$("#add").click(function () {
   if(pressCounter >= 6){
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }else {
     pressCounter += 1;
     inputVal = $("#my-input").val();
     inputVal = Number(inputVal);
     total += inputVal;
     console.log(total); // print total. just for test
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="my-input">
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

Answer (score 0):

Push all numbers provided in an array one after the other and use reduce method to get the sum. Before finding the sum you can use yourArray.length to find the amount of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with an array of values, if that is the case:

```
if (values.length > 5) {
    // disable your button

    var i, len = values.length, total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        // add up total
        total += values[i];
    }

    // display your total
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$('p').each(function(a,b) {...` or .find('p').each(function(a,b)` a will be the index number of the paragraph. So add a check like

```
if (a < 6) {
  ...
}
```

It does mean iterating over more p's than are actually used, but the cost of that is minimal

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#aadd").click(function () {
     var arrayy = JSON.parse("[" + $("#my-input").val() + "]");
     console.log("Length of array = "+arrayy.length)
     if(arrayy.length<6 ||arrayy.length>6)
     {
        alert("Please enter 6 values");
     }
    /*Write your logic to add 6 numbers in array*/ 
  }); 
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="my-input" value="1,2,3,4,5,6">
  <input type="button" id="aadd" value="Add">
</body>
</html>
```